# How can i make a button that pastes what's on my clipboard to any location?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm new to C#, so..
I want to make a button that pastes what's on my TextBox to any text form.

Example:
I write something on my Textbox.A
I press the button, then the button copy what's in this textbox and when i click something it will automatically paste it.

I already did the "Copy" part, i just need to do the "Paste" part.

Thank you!

Comment: Automatically paste the text where? To another location (text box etc.) in your application, to a completely different application?

Comment: To a completely different application.
Like, if I click on the text region on another region it's intended to paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your task is to paste this text once outside the form, then you can use this code.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(textBox1.Text);
        Deactivate += Form1_Deactivate; //next click will invoke the Form's Deactivate event
    }

    private void Form1_Deactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("^v");
        Deactivate -= Form1_Deactivate;
    }
```

Comment: Also, how can i make the form press enter automatically after pasting the TextBox content?

Comment: @MatheusKlein just add `SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}")` after sending `"^v"` and Enter will be emulated too.
More here:[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you! Also, can i make a loop?

Comment: Like, copy and pasting without stopping or this isn't possible?

Comment: Not this way. This solution works for only single paste because Form_Deactivate event raises once.

Comment: Is there any way that i can do this?

Comment: This is not a solution. It fails on systems, where [Ctrl]+V is not the shortcut for pasting data from the clipboard, for example. An appropriate solution would either send a [WM_PASTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649028.aspx) message, or use [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable this is not robust scalable enterprise solution, but if author said it helped, this is still solution. Author also said he is newbie, so your options is obvious overhead for him.

Comment: The application is designed for Windows users only, so this is ok.
But i still want to know how can i activate a loop while pasting.. anyone know how to do it?

Comment: @MatheusKlein consider creating a new question for this.

Comment: I can't create another question. Seems like that i reached the limit, I have to wait 3 days.

Comment: Answers on stackoverflow are not meant to help just the individual developer, that asked a question. Answers should be generally applicable. This one isn't.

Comment: @IInspectable maybe you could propose an edit if it is not massive.

Comment: @DanilGaponov: A proposed edit would essentially remove everything, and add a new answer. If I find time, I may add a new answer altogether.